Usar Multiples archivos ensamblador ARM en un proyecyto
Soy estudiante de electrónica y estoy aprendiendo a usar el lenguaje ensamblador en un ARM Cortex-M4, específicamente para el microcontrolador STM32F401CCUx y, aún más específico, en la tarjeta BlackPill (estoy usando Keil uVision, la versión actual a la fecha de esta publicación). Mientras trabajaba en mi proyecto de inicialización y manipulación de una LCD 16x2, me pregunté si alguna vez en la historia se han usado varios archivos de ensamblador para un solo proyecto y cómo se comunican entre sí para mantener un mayor orden en el proyecto.
Hasta ahora, lo he intentado y no lo he logrado. Quiero hacer uso solo de archivos .s
Tener un archivo el cual pueda llamar dentro de mi código principal únicamente para la inicialización y, en mi principal, enviar los datos. He intentado con las directivas Export, Import y Get, "BL LR" y "BX LR" pero no he tenido éxito. Me gustaría saber si algún lector pudiera orientarme para lograr mi objetivo.
Mi meta es aprender y manejar el ensamblador como un profesional... Jejeje

